# solve the equation $1+2z+2z^2+\ldots +2z^{n-1}+z^n=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

im trying to solve the equation  $$(E)\quad 1+2z+2z^2+\ldots +2z^{n-1}+z^n=0$$

attempt : because $1$ isnt a solution we have  $$\begin{aligned}
1+2 z+2 z^{2}+\cdots+2 z^{n-1}+z^{n} &=2\left(z^{0}+z+z^{2}+\cdots+z^{n-1}\right)-1+z^{n} \\
&=2 \frac{1-z^{n}}{1-z}-1+z^{n} \\
&=\frac{2-2 z^{n}+z^{n}-z^{n+1}}{1-z}-1 \\
&=\frac{2-z^{n}-z^{n+1}}{1-z}-1
\end{aligned}$$ then (E) becomes $$z^{n+1}+z^{n}-z-1=0$$ but i dont know how to get any further.

Comment: Factor both sides by $z + 1$.

Comment: This is $(z^n-1)(z+1)=0$. So for example $z=-1$ is always a solution, and any $n$-root of unity for given $n\ge 2$.

Comment: and then the solutions are $-1$ and the n-roots of unity , thankss

Comment: @DonnieDarko ...except $z = 1$. This is an erroneous solution introduced when using the geometric series formula, then subsequently multiplying by $z - 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
1 + 2z + 2z^2 + \cdots + 2z^{n-1} + z^n 
&= (1 + z + \cdots + z^{n-1}) + (z + z^2 + \cdots + z^n) \\
&= (1+z)(1 + z + z^2 + \cdots + z^{n-1}) \\
&= \frac{(z+1)(z^n - 1)}{z - 1}.
\end{align}$$

Thus the roots are $$z \in \{ e^{2\pi i k/n} : k \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\} \} \cup \{ -1 \}.$$  When $n$ is even, $-1$ is a double root; when $n$ is odd, it is a single root.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: \begin{align}
z^{n+1}+z^n-z-1&=z^n(z+1)-(z+1)\\
&=(z^n-1)(z+1)
\end{align}

Also, I think you should justify why the second equality holds, i.e. explain why you can assume $1-z\neq 0$.